# Adding Data to NSArray from Parse query

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform, nsstring

so my app stores a friends first name in key `firstName` , last name in key `lastName`, and username in a parse  class called `friendsAssociation` in addition it also stores the signed in user's username in an object called user. I would like to query the data to find all instances where the user object equals the user's username. I would then like to store the first name of the friends in an array.

Here is a copy of the code I am trying to use

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendsAssociation"];
//quesrys the class Friend asssociation to find when instances of "user" equal the
//logged in user's username
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:_user];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d users.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        if (objects.count == 0) {
            //uialert letting the user know that no phone number matches the query
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No User"  message:@"No user matches this username"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        //if there is an object matching the query
        if (objects.count >=1) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", objects);}
            firstname[objects.count]= [object objectforkey:@"firstName"];
       }
        //if there is more than one phonenumber matching the query as
        //the user to input the friends username
        //instead
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
 }];
```

specifically i would like to use this for loop to store the data in an `NSArray` called firstname

```
   for (PFObject *object in objects) {
      NSLog(@"%@", objects);}
      firstname[objects.count]= [object objectforkey:@"firstName"];
   }
```

However, I am not able to have the line `[object objectforkey:@"firstName"]` because object is not declared. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax problem in your `for` loop (closing it with a `}` before `object` is even used).

Try this:

```
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
    NSLog(@"%@", object);
    [firstname addObject:[object objectforkey:@"firstName"]];
}
```

**EDIT**: by doing this, you will probably have to balance the removal of the closing curly braces with another one left open earlier in your code...